# Build Failure when running the Project through maven install

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, maven-install-plugin

Trying to run Project in Eclipse by `Right Click Project>>Run As>>Maven Install`

I have only 2 Test Cases in my `src\\tests` folder and both the Test Cases are running Fine. After the Tests got completed, Getting Build Failure in Console.

> Error:-Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   (default-test) on project selenium-project: Execution default-test of
>   goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   failed: There was an error in the forked process
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException

Please Refer the below Screenshot
[image]

Comment: are you using testNG ?

Comment: @RAMANDOGRA Can you consider updating your maven project folder structure, pom.xml & your code block please? Thanks

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution yes I am using TestNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following way to execute your test  from testing.xml file using Maven

Add one `Testing.xml` file in project root. Content will be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuit">
  <test name="MyTest">
         <classes>      
                        <class name="package.subpackage.TestClassName"/>            
         </classes> 
  </test>
</suite>
```

Add Below code in your `pom.xml` just above `<dependencies>` tag

```
     <!-- Following plugin executes the testing tests  -->
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.4</version>
               <configuration>    
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                 </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>                       
        </plugin> 

          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>     
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

Do below steps

Right Click on Project > Run As > Maven Clean

Then

Right Click on Project > Run As > Maven Build

Then

Right Click on Project > Run As > Maven Test

Comment: Thanks it finally worked for me..
Actually complier -plugin was missing in my pom.xml

Comment: The Above changes working fine while running Project independently but while running it from Jenkins, My build getting failed. Here is the Console Output Error.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings()
 at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest()
 at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest()
 at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main()
  Failed to parse POMs

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: The error says it all `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1` which points out that <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId><version>2.19.1</version> is already installed. Thanks

Comment: Here is my POM.xml